# Error when combining flysystem and liipImageBundle libraries in symfony6

Tags: php, symfony, liipimaginebundle, flysystem

I use Symfony 6 and ApiPlatform.
I want to put out miniature photos. I am using Flysystem and LiipImagineBundle.
I did everything as in the Symfony documentation. However, when I want to use the method "filterService-> getUrlOfFilteredImage ()"
I get an error:

> Liip\ImagineBundle\Binary\Loader\FlysystemV2Loader::__construct():
> Argument #2 ($filesystem) must be of type
> League\Flysystem\FilesystemOperator,
> League\Flysystem\Local\LocalFilesystemAdapter given, called in
> /var/www/var/cache/dev/Container6Sb4vUT/getLiipImagine_Binary_Loader_FlysystemLoaderService.php
> on line 23

Is this a library bug?

My config.yml

```
liip_imagine:
    # valid drivers options include "gd" or "gmagick" or "imagick"
    driver: "imagick"

    loaders:
        flysystem_loader:
            flysystem:
                filesystem_service: flysystem.adapter.private.storage
    data_loader: flysystem_loader

    filter_sets:
        my_thumb:
            filters:
                thumbnail:
                    size: [200, 200]
                    mode: outbound
                    allow_upscale: true


############################
flysystem:
    storages:
        private.storage:
            adapter: 'local'
            options:
                directory: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/storage/files'
```

Answer (score 0):

As I found out in [this](https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem-bundle/issues/62#issuecomment-785105754) comment on a Github issue, you have to exclude the `flysystem.adapter` part in the `filesystem_service` key.

Leaving only `private.storage` in your case. As such :

```
liip_imagine:
  driver: "imagick"

loaders:
    flysystem_loader:
        flysystem:
            filesystem_service: private.storage
```